# Transfer symfony logfiles with filebeat to graylog in local docker-environment

Tags: symfony, docker, elasticsearch, filebeat, graylog2

### Description

I am trying to build an equal configuration in my local docker-environment like on our production system. After spending some time investigating and rebuilding the docker container setup, still can't get it to work and Graylog is not receiving any data.

### Overview and interim results

- *web*, *php* and *db* container are in use for the symfony based application
- symfony runs properly on localhost in php-container and generates logfiles
- symfony-logfiles are located here: /var/www/html/var/logs/*.log
- symfony-logfiles format is json / gelf
- all other containers are also up and running when starting the complete composition
- filebeat configuration is based on first link below
- filebeat.yml seems to retrieve any logfile found in any container
- filebeat configured to transfer data directly to elasticsearch
- elasticsearch persists data in mongodb
- all graylog related data in persisted in named volumes in docker
- additionally I am working with docker-sync on a Mac

### The docker-compose.yml is based on the following resources:

- https://github.com/jochenchrist/docker-logging-elasticsearch
- http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/installation/docker.html?highlight=docker
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.3/running-on-docker.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.3/filebeat-reference-yml.html

### config.yml

```
# Monolog Configuration
monolog:
  channels: [graylog]
  handlers:
    graylog:
      type:      stream
      formatter: line_formatter
      path:      "%kernel.logs_dir%/graylog.log"
      channels:  [graylog]
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        links:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ./docker-config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - project-app-sync:/var/www/html
            - ./docker-config/localhost.crt:/etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.crt
            - ./docker-config/localhost.key:/etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.key

    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker-config/Dockerfile-php
        links:
            - graylog
        volumes:
            - project-app-sync:/var/www/html
            - ./docker-config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
            - ./docker-config/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

    db:
        image: mysql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=project
            - MYSQL_USER=project
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
        volumes:
            - ./docker-config/mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
            - project-mysql-sync:/var/lib/mysql

    # Graylog / Filebeat

    filebeat:
        build: ./docker-config/filebeat
        volumes:
          - /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers:ro
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        networks:
          - graylog-network
        depends_on:
          - graylog-elasticsearch

    graylog:
        image: graylog/graylog:2.4
        volumes:
          - graylog-journal:/usr/share/graylog/data/journal
        networks:
          - graylog-network
        environment:
          - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=somepasswordpepper
          - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
          - GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI=http://127.0.0.1:9000/api
        links:
          - graylog-mongo:mongo
          - graylog-elasticsearch:elasticsearch
        depends_on:
          - graylog-mongo
          - graylog-elasticsearch
        ports:
          # Graylog web interface and REST API
          - 9000:9000

    graylog-mongo:
        image: mongo:3
        volumes:
            - graylog-mongo-data:/data/db
        networks:
            - graylog-network

    graylog-elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.10
        ports:
            - "9200:9200"
        volumes:
            - graylog-elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        networks:
            - graylog-network
        environment:
            - cluster.name=graylog
            - "discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1"
            - "discovery.type=single-node"
            - http.host=0.0.0.0
            - transport.host=localhost
            - network.host=0.0.0.0
            # Disable X-Pack security: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/security-settings.html#general-security-settings
            - xpack.security.enabled=false
            - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
        ulimits:
            memlock:
                soft: -1
                hard: -1

volumes:
    project-app-sync:
        external: true
    project-mysql-sync: ~
    graylog-mongo-data:
        driver: local
    graylog-elasticsearch-data:
        driver: local
    graylog-journal:
        driver: local

networks:
    graylog-network: ~
```

### Dockerfile of filebeat container

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.3.1
COPY filebeat.yml /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
# must run as root to access /var/lib/docker and /var/run/docker.sock
USER root
RUN chown root /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
# dont run with -e, to disable output to stderr
CMD [""]
```

### filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: docker
  paths:
    - '/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log'
    # path to symfony based logs
    - '/var/www/html/var/logs/*.log'
  containers.ids: '*'

processors:
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["host","application","short_message"]
      target: ""
      overwrite_keys: true
  - add_docker_metadata: ~

output.elasticsearch:
  # transfer data to elasticsearch container?
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

logging.to_files: true
logging.to_syslog: false
```

### Graylog backend

After setting up this docker composition I started the Graylog web-view and set up a collector and input as described here:

- http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/collector_sidecar.html#step-by-step-guide

Maybe I have totally misunderstood how this could work. I am not totally sure if Beats from Elastic is the same as the filebeats container and if the sidecar collector is something extra I forgot to add. Maybe I misconfigured the collector and input in graylog?!

I would be thankful to any help or working example according to my problem ...

Answer (score 2):

Graylog seems to be running on `http://127.0.0.1:9000/api` which is in the container. You might want to run it as `http://graylog:9000/api` or as `http://0.0.0.0:9000/api`

Accessing the other images from within any of the other images will have be done with the same name as the `service` name, as defined in the `docker-compose.yml` files. The url to the graylog-elasticsearch would be something like: `http://graylog-elasticsearch/....` if you would post to `localhost` it would stay inside its own image.

Hope this will help you along in finding the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations! Based on your proposed changes I made some modifications in the docker-compose.yml and the filebeat.yml but unfortunately still there seems no messages to arrive in the graylog backend.